# NPE in Mahout TopItems#getTopUsers

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mahout, mahout-recommender

I'm using the mahout version 0.9. I have got NPE at demo server with following stacktrace.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerExceptiontype Exception reportmessage Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerExceptiondescription The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.exception org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.TopItems.getTopUsers(TopItems.java:119)
 org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.neighborhood.NearestNUserNeighborhood.getUserNeighborhood(NearestNUserNeighborhood.java:94)
 org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.GenericUserBasedRecommender.recommend(GenericUserBasedRecommender.java:87)
 org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.recommender.AbstractRecommender.recommend(AbstractRecommender.java:63)
 .....recommendationengine.service.RecommendationService.findRecommendedProductsForOpportunityByMahout(RecommendationService.java:69)
 .....recommendationengine.controller.RecommendationController.recommendedForOpportunity(RecommendationController.java:54)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
 org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.40 logs.Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
```

After restart the server for debugging problem not reproduced. I have download the source code of Mahout 0.9 and can't understand how it's possible take NPE at **TopItems.java:119**, one possible case it if **topItems** Queue is empty but it's impossible if I'm correct understand the code in method. 
Could any one help me with this NPE?

Thank you guys.

**Update**
NPE is possible if **howMany** param is 0, but I'm using 5. Will research it....

**Update 2** **howMany** param can't be less than 1 because it's checked in constructor of NearestNUserNeighborhood. I have no ideas more... :(

Comment: Are you saying that restarting the server fixed the problem?

Comment: Yes and it not reproduced any more.

Comment: A non-reproducable error generally doesn't get much attention. What you describe should not happen and does not happen for the vast majority of users. If you want you can file a bug on the Mahout bug  tracker give as much information as you can give.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was hasted on Heroku and was going to sleep some times. I think it was reproduced after resume app.
Question can be closed.